# InputStream istr = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/Libro_1.xml"); is always null

Tags: xml, inputstream, codenameone

I really don't know why, but the result of InputStream istr = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/Libro_1.xml"); is always null.

I' m sure the location is right, the case is right, but the result is always the same: istr=null.

Can you help me explaining me why?

I have read some topics about similar issue, and it seems to me everything is as it should be...

Thank's in advance,
Luca

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGCiz.png)

Comment: I followed advices from here: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html

Comment: Please, someone can help me understand where am I wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the /Libro_1.xml directly under the project root.
src/Libro_1.xml

Comment: Ottimo, great... Thank's a lot!

Comment: can you please mark this as a correct answer if that helped you, thanks